# How to pre populate data between the screens in android

Tags: android, persistence

I have an app with 3 screens.

For each screens i have next button in each screen  to go to the next screen.

**problem:**

**Scenario 1:**

> --> I filled the data in first screen
>
> --> I go to the second screen.
>
> --> When i come back to the first page i am able to see the data what i filled.
>
> -->But when i again go to the second page i am not able to see the data what i filled in the second form.

How  can i manage this in android?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Add your code about second and first activity realted to filled data into activity 2

Comment: You can use static values or serialize your data.

Comment: @PankajKumar i need to pre populate  data in second screen.Is it possible ?

Comment: Ok. I got that. Explain how you send data to one activity to another? As you said that you can get data of second screen at first screen.. so what did you do? Can you share code?

Comment: Actually i did not do any thing for that.It is by default populating by clicking on back button

Comment: @PankajKumar When i am going to the next page ,that page is not populating the previous data.

Comment: Did you populated values into onResume/ onCreate of second actiivty?

Comment: I think onCreate  means activity starts from first.How i can get the previous values ?

Comment: Thats why I am asking about the code.

Comment: @PankajKumar can u wait for 2mins

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42308/discussion-between-psr-and-pankaj-kumar)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data in Shared preferences. Check this :  [Shared Preferences Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and  [Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the state yourself using your activities' lifecycle methods. Read this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

You can save temporary data in application data. Once in the `onCreate` method, you can reuse that data, or you can use an activity flag to ensure that there's only one instance of your activity in the backstack.

Answer (score 0):

```
            try
            {
                //in first run app. go to catch and in other go to try
                SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref",0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
                String x= pref.getString("login", null);
                edit.commit();
                if(x.equals("first"))
                {
                    //here you can fill editbox by value you entered before
                    edt1.setText(x);
                    //and make this way to all edittext 
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref",0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
                edit.putString("login",edt1.getText().toString());  
                //edt1.getText().toString() value(s) you want to save
                edit.commit();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), First.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```